# Canvas does not render chart correctly

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I´m using these libraries:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.js
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels

but when render the labels are cut.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXr20.png)

I expected this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6qx6.png)

`const ctx_new = document.getElementById('grafica_nueva');
window.Chart.defaults.global.showTooltips = false;

```
        grafica_new =  new window.Chart(ctx_new, {
            type: 'outlabeledDoughnut',
            data: dataPage.dataGraph,
            options: {
                zoomOutPercentage: 70,
                plugins: {
                    outlabels: {
                        text: (val)=>{
                            let valor  = val.dataset.data[val.dataIndex];
                            if(parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2) > 0.0){
                    
                                const saldoName = dataPage.saldos.filter((v,i) => v.saldo === valor);
                                const total_saldo = dataPage.saldos.reduce((total, elemento) => total + elemento.saldo, 0);
                                const porcentaje = (valor * 100) / total_saldo;
                                return `${saldoName[0].plan}\n$${nWithCommas(parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2))}\n${parseFloat(porcentaje).toFixed(2)}%`
                            }else{
                                return ''
                            }
                            
                        },
                        color: 'white',
                        font: {
                            resizable: true,
                            minSize: 12,
                            maxSize: 18
                        },
                    },
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false // <-- this option disables tooltips
                  }
              }
        });`
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, would you mind adding the data you are rendering?